# PHP include not working - because of server config?

Tags: php, html, include

I have the following two files:

1. www.domain.com/test.php
2. www.domain.com/sub/test.php

I want to include the sub file in the root file and tried the following:

```
<?php
  include ("http://www.domain.com/sub/test.php");
?>
```

...but that fails to work. I also tried using `include("/sub/test.php");` but get the same result **(i.e. empty page).**

`phpinfo()` gives me the following information:

- include_path .:
- allow_url_include    Off

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: remove the leading backslash. That says go to the root of the drive and start looking for a directory called `sub` which aint there `include('sub/test.php');`

Comment: Learn about include paths, `include 'sub/test.php';` Why would you even want to include a ***local*** file using a url????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration is pretty clear:

```
allow_url_include Off
```

This means including of URL files is denied on that server.

For the rest - `include "sub/test.php"` should work (note the removed slash from the beginning). Also note the path is relative to your current directory or it looks up the file in the current `include_path`.

Comment: Works, thanks a lot. I'll mark it as solved as soon as possible